# convert date to number in javascript

Tags: javascript, date, numbers

I'm using google app script for some application and in javascript m getting `NaN` error

```
var state = $("#state").text();
var now = new Date();
var startDate = $("#startDate").val();
var endDate = $("#endDate").val();
var sdate=Number(startDate);
var edate=Number(endDate);
var empName = $("#searchEmpName").val();
alert(edate+","+sdate);

if (edate < sdate){
  // show error msg
}
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `var sdate = parseInt(startDate);` instead of `var sdate = Number(startDate);` and same for the end date.

Comment: as start date is 26/01/2018 and end date is 31/12/2017 is not working as it only compare date

Comment: so you can use `var sdate = new Date(startDate); var integerDate = sdate.getTime();` and same for the end date. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

`var sdate=new Date(startDate);`
`var edate=new Date(endDate);`
Here no need to convert sdate and edate in Number.
You can compare both the dates now as you have done before.